# Confusions in windows based design of FIR filters?

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, finite-impulse-response, window-functions

I am reading the proakis book"DSP USING MATLAB 3rd Edition"

In chap 7, article 7.3, i came across example 7.8,where i saw formulas for pass band ripple and stop band attenuation
I have highlighted them in attached snapshot but i couldn't find out how they were calculated

Please also include reference of these formulas of Rp and As, into your answer, as i could not find their reference in book

and also what is "delta_w"?Is it "transition width"? and also i am unable to understand formula of "M" especially first term ceil(6.6pi/tr_width)

I am also pasting here link of my another relevant question
[Confusion calculating length of Kaiser window](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69327/confusion-calculating-length-of-kaiser-window)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From the code you can see that they compute the maximum passband ripple by computing the minimum value of the filter's magnitude response in the passband. Similarly, they compute the maximum value of the magnitude response in the stopband, corresponding to the maximum stopband ripple.

The formula for estimating the filter length $M$ can be found in Table 7.1 on page 330 of Proakis' book. It is specific for the chosen Hamming window.

Comment: Can you please also include reference of these formulas of Rp and As, into your answer, as i could  not find their reference in book

Comment: @engr: There are no "formulas", just think about what they're trying to do: they look at the magnitude response in dB and check its minimum value in the passband (where it should ideally be 0 dB), and its maximum value in the stopband (where it should ideally be 0, i.e., $-\infty$ dB). These are the maximum deviations from the ideal values, that's all.

Comment: @engr: The transition width is clearly `tr_width`, not `delta_w`. The latter is just the spacing between the frequency points in the vector `w`, returned by `freqz_m`. As for passband and stopband ripple, please re-read my answer. I'm not sure what you don't understand. There's no 'reference' for such a computation. If you want to know the maximum value of a filter's response in the stopband, then you just compute it the way they did in the code, as simple as that. That maximum value in dB is the minimum attenuation of the filter. Ideally the filter's response should be zero in the stopband.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable and helpful posts( answer and comment)for this question.

Comment: I really appreciate your kind time and efforts. Please try to look into this updated question and also into Linked question. Thanks again

Comment: @engr: I've added an explanation for the formula used to estimate `M`.